Unity socket.on not receive
all, first of all thanks for help. I have a Unity project trying to send mesh over sockets. If I run on same Unity executable it works, I can emit and receive from the same port 8080, but with separates executables, it seems that socket.On is not receiving.
This is my server.js:
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http, {
    maxHttpBufferSize: 10e6 // Aumenta el límite a 10 MB
});

http.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on port 8080');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');

    socket.on('mesh', (data) => {
        console.log('Message from client', data);
        socket.emit('mesh', data); // Reenvía los mismos datos recibidos al cliente
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});

My socketIO client:
public class SocketIO_Client : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SocketIOUnity socket;
    public string serverUrlLink = "http://localhost:8080";

    [Header ("JSON")]
    public string jsonReceived;
    public string textureReceived;

    void Start()
    {
        var uri = new Uri(serverUrlLink);
        socket = new SocketIOUnity(uri);

        socket.OnConnected += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Debug.Log("socket.OnConnected");
        };

        // Listen
        socket.On("mesh", response =>
        {
            Debug.Log("Event : " + response.ToString());
            //Debug.Log(response.GetValue<string>());

            // jsonReceived = response.ToString();

        });

        socket.Connect();
    }

    public void SentMesh(string mesh)
    {
        // save file
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Application.dataPath + "/MeshLog_json_compressed_sent.txt"))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(mesh);
            Debug.Log("MeshLog.txt saved : " + Application.dataPath + "/MeshLog_json_compressed_sent.txt");
        }

        socket.EmitAsync("mesh", mesh);
        Debug.Log("Emited Mesh");
    }

    public void SentTexture(string texture)
    {
        socket.EmitAsync("texture", texture);
        Debug.Log("Emited Texture");
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        socket.Dispose();
    }
}


port sharing is not usually done, you cant usually have 2 separate things listening on the same port.. you can one many separates connect to the same port, but not listen.

Sorry but to me it looks like you are not calling SentMesh or SendTexture anywhere. Could you try to append at the end of Start() method SentMesh("someMesh") and tell us what happens? From what I see, the code should be working well.

SOLVED. changed line
socket.emit('mesh', data); 

To :
io.emit('mesh', data); 

All clients receive the data. Thanks for help !!
